# Encrypt Gibberish nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby, encryption

I am trying to Implement Gibberish encryption using the following class:

```
class Encrypt
    def initialize()
        @cipher = Gibberish::AES.new("Kudzu")
    end
    def encode(caller)
        if((caller.is_a? Account) || (caller.is_a? Atm))
            return @cipher.enc("Kumquat")
        else
            return false
        end
    end

    def decode(caller, key)
        if((caller.is_a? Account) || (caller.is_a? Atm))
            return @cipher.dec(key)
        else
            return false
        end
    end
end
```

Instantiating using:

```
$encrypt = Encrypt.new
```

and calling in my Atm class using:

```
@key = $encrypt.encode(self)
```

The error i receive is thus:

```
undefined method `encode' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
```

Is there something i'm not understanding about gibberish or some other silly error on my part?

Also in my Account class:

```
@key = $encrypt.decode(self, $encrypt.encode(self))
```

Comment: Are you sure you are calling `$encrypt = Encrypt.new` _before_ calling `@key = $encrypt.encode(self)`?

Comment: yes but i also tried moving it around to no avail. I have no way of  knowing if this is true but i cant think of any other explanation other than perhaps i installed openssl incorrectly. (seems unlikely since i installed it using git) *shrug* I see no reason why it shouldn't work, i'll just try a different approach thanks for taking a look guys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$encrypt` is ending up `nil` somehow in your Atm class.  Can't be much more helpful without seeing all the code.  Keep in mind that [Global Variables are Evil](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/148108/why-is-global-state-so-evil) (using $variable in ruby) and try to rework your code so you don't need them..